# Reporting Services: multiple subreports in one report

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, subreports

in my project there are three reports - Main Report and two subreports, each with its own dataset (the only column common to all the datasets is ItemID). The Main Report passes ItemID as parameter to each of its two subreports.

The Main Report is built in a form-like layout, i.e. I use the List control and arrange the Main Report fields inside the List body. (I need to show only one record each time, so I chose List and not Table or Matrix.)

If I add one of the subreports to the Main Report body (i.e. inside the List body), it works just fine. But if I try to add the other subreport to the Main Report, the data is shown only in the subreports while the fields of the Main Reports are empty (no data from the dataset of the Main Report is shown). I can't understand why it happens.

What could be the problem here?

I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: I've created many reports with the same basic structure that you describe: repeating detail rows that contain multiple sub-reports. There must be something else causing the problems. Can you place just the second subreport successfully? Maybe the query for one subreport causes problems for the other subreport's query?

Comment: If I place one of the subreports (it doesn't matter which one) it works successfully. But if I place both of them, it doesn't. I've checked the queries of all three reports and couldn't spot the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved the problem by placing each of the subreports in a rectangle of its own, instead of placing them both directly in the rectangle of the List's body.

I should use rectangles more often...

Comment: +1 I had a feeling that was the answer, but your answer just confirmed it for me. I have been using rectangles for a lot of things, great for grouping things together.